Why is my @Recorder, use in a custum Quarkus Extension, a proxy?
Im unable run testet in Intellij, using kotlin, the @Recoder is not registering as a @Recorder in quarkus-core-deployment. The when I take a look in the debugger i can se that the recorder is a Proxy object. Why dos this happen? When do Quarkus create proxy objects and can i disable it for å class?

This is not a problem when running form command line. This line is the problem in quarkus-core-development that dosent work with a Proxy class:
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static boolean isRecorder(AnnotatedElement element) {
    return element.isAnnotationPresent(Recorder.class);
}

I want to able to run testes in Intellij without a problem and not get this stacktrace:
Failed to load steps from class [hidden]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load steps from class [hidden]
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:169)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:107)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:350)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:272)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:219)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:601)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:651)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: public void [hidden],[hidden].BeanContainerBuildItem,[hidden]) is marked @Record but does not inject an @Recorder object
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFromClass(ExtensionLoader.java:467)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:167)
    ... 8 more


When the build time part of the extension is being run, the recorder is a proxy because at build time the recorders are not actually executed, instead they are used to capture the values of the parameters passed to them - and using proxies is the easiest way to intercept the calls and capture the values

That makes sens, but in this case I am unable to run build step because element.isAnnotationPresent(Recorder.class) return false on a proxy. Is this a bug in Quarkus deploy? The class has the annotation Recorder annotation.

I can't say I understand what you are seeing. Do you have the code somewhere I can try?

I'm sorry the code is internal and we decided to just try something else :)
